# hide a barchart section in excel graph but display it data table..vb winforms

Tags: excel, vb.net, winforms, excel-charts

All

I seem to have issue and I am not sure if its doable. I am trying to remove a particular section of column stacked chart created in excel but still show the row in the data table. See the image to make more sense of my problem statement
[image: Show row and remove section of the graph]

This graph is generated as in excel file output from my vb winforms application
Here is code that creates the chart

```
    'Create a Chart
    Dim ChartPage As Excel.Chart
    Dim xlCharts As Excel.ChartObjects
    Dim myChart As Excel.ChartObject
    Dim chartRange As Excel.Range

    xlCharts = xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects
    myChart = xlCharts.Add(3, 100, 650, 300)
    ChartPage = myChart.Chart
    chartRange = xlWorkSheet.Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells(10, 1), xlWorkSheet.Cells(10 + lstRows.Count, 1 + lstCols.Count))
    ChartPage.SetSourceData(Source:=chartRange)
    ChartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnStacked
    ChartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue).MajorGridLines.Delete()
    ChartPage.HasDataTable = True
    ChartPage.ApplyDataLabels(Excel.XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue)

    Dim tq = ChartPage.SeriesCollection
    For Each itm In ChartPage.SeriesCollection
        itm.DataLabels.Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
    Next
```

Comment: The only way I know to accomplish your desired visual, would be to place two chart objects on the same ChartSheet and put the one with Totals data behind and slightly below the one with the desired Series.  See: [Place multiple charts on a chart sheet in Excel](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/place-multiple-charts-on-a-chart-sheet-in-excel/) for some rudimentary instructions.

Comment: @TnTinMn I ended up going that route..Thanks Not perfect but will work for my situation